# What is the n-th sum that has binomial coefficients?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Here's the problem : $\sum_{k=2}^{n}{(k-1)(n-k)!{n \choose k}}$

My approach is to do something with $\frac{n!}{2!}+2\frac{n!}{3!}+3\frac{n!}{4!}+...+(n-1)\frac{n!}{n!}$

Then I'll have a sum $n!(\sum_{k=2}^{n}{\frac{k-1}{k!}})$ and it works as  @player3236 showed, but I was tasked to use properties of binomial coefficients to evaluate this sum.

Such that ${n \choose k} = {n \choose k-1}$ and ${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k}$

Answer (score 3):

The sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^n \frac {k-1}{k!}$ is not related to the harmonic series.

Observe that $$\frac {k-1}{k!} = \frac k{k!}-\frac 1{k!} = \frac{1}{(k-1)!} - \frac 1{k!}$$

so that sum actually telescopes to $1-\dfrac 1{n!}$.

Comment: Do you mean in the last line $1-1/n$ ?